# Javascript doesn't toggle the display of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I'm trying to obtain multiple slideshows on my website.
I have done almost everything, excepting the fact that when I press a picture, the modal of previews is showing, but the clicked image is not showing up. I have to use the buttons of the slideshow to go through them and make the first one to appear.
**

### If you don't want to go along this whole code, here you can see what's happening: http://beta.eduardstefan.com

**
**I am not trying to promote myself, I just think that I am not quite easy to understand without the example**

So, my question, how can I make the first picture to show up when I press one, or why it's not happening, what is bad with my code?

My html:

```
<div class="portfolio-slideshow">
    <a class="prev" onclick="slide(0,-1)">❮</a>
    <div class="slide"> <img src="img/dailyui/008.png" class="slideimg_0" id="0" data-no="0"> </div>
    <div class="slide"> <img src="img/dailyui/007.jpg" class="slideimg_0" id="1" data-no="0"> </div>
    <div class="slide"> <img src="img/dailyui/006.jpg" class="slideimg_0" id="2" data-no="0"> </div>
    <div class="slide"> <img src="img/dailyui/003.jpg" class="slideimg_0" id="3" data-no="0"> </div>
    <a class="next" onclick="slide(0,1)">❯</a>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-slideshow">
    <a class="prev" onclick="slide(2,-1)">❮</a>
    <div class="slide"> <img src="img/dailyui/008.png" class="slideimg_2" id="0" data-no="2"> </div>
    <div class="slide"> <img src="img/dailyui/007.jpg" class="slideimg_2" id="1" data-no="2"> </div>
    <div class="slide"> <img src="img/dailyui/006.jpg" class="slideimg_2" id="2" data-no="2"> </div>
    <div class="slide"> <img src="img/dailyui/003.jpg" class="slideimg_2" id="3" data-no="2"> </div>
    <a class="next" onclick="slide(2,1)">❯</a>
</div>

<div class="imgpreview">
    <i class="fa fa-close" onclick="closepreview()"></i>
    <div class="slidepreview no_0">
        <a class="prev" onclick="slide(1,-1)">❮</a>
        <div class="slidep"> <img src="img/dailyui/008.png" class="slideimg_1" id="0"> </div>
        <div class="slidep"> <img src="img/dailyui/007.jpg" class="slideimg_1" id="1"> </div>
        <div class="slidep"> <img src="img/dailyui/006.jpg" class="slideimg_1" id="2"> </div>
        <div class="slidep"> <img src="img/dailyui/003.jpg" class="slideimg_1" id="3"> </div>
        <a class="next" onclick="slide(1,1)">❯</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slidepreview no_2">
        <a class="prev" onclick="slide(3,-1)">❮</a>
        <div class="slidep"> <img src="img/dailyui/008.png" class="slideimg_3" id="0"> </div>
        <div class="slidep"> <img src="img/dailyui/007.jpg" class="slideimg_3" id="1"> </div>
        <div class="slidep"> <img src="img/dailyui/006.jpg" class="slideimg_3" id="2"> </div>
        <div class="slidep"> <img src="img/dailyui/003.jpg" class="slideimg_3" id="3"> </div>
        <a class="next" onclick="slide(3,1)">❯</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.portfolio-slideshow{
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.slide{
    padding:0 35px;
    display: block;

    img{
        display: none;
        max-height:40vh;
        max-width:100%;
    }
}
.prev,.next{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.imgpreview{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 50px;
}

.slidepreview{
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

.slidep{
    display: block;

    img{
        display: none;
        max-height: 85vh;
        max-width: 85vw;
    }
}
```

And Javascript:

```
var slideIndex = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
function showSlides(){
    var aux = slideIndex.length;
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<aux; i+=2) { slide(i,0); }
}

function slide(n,m){
    var i;
    var aux = document.getElementsByClassName("slideimg_" + n);
    var aux2 = aux.length - 1;
    if (slideIndex[n] == 3 && m == 1) slideIndex[n] = -1;
    if (slideIndex[n] == 0 && m == -1) slideIndex[n] = 4;
    slideIndex[n] += m;
    if (slideIndex[n] < 0) slideIndex = aux2;
    else if (slideIndex[n] > aux2) slideIndex = 0;
    for(i=0; i<aux.length; i++){
        aux[i].style.display = "none";
        aux[i].parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
    aux[slideIndex[n]].style.display = "block";
    aux[slideIndex[n]].parentElement.style.display = 'block';
}

function closepreview(){
    $('.imgpreview').css("display" , "none");
    $('.slidepreview').css("display" , "none")
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slide img").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var no = $(this).attr('data-no');
        var no2 = no + 1;

        $(".imgpreview").css("display" , "flex");
        $(".no_" + no).css("display" , "flex");
        $("img#" + id + ".slideimg_" + no2).css("display" , "block");
        slideIndex[no2] = id;
    });
}).resize();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IDs must be unique.

Instead of inline event handlers I would suggest to attach them to the js code (separate html from js code).

I removed all IDs and I changed everything in jQuery using:

- [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)
- [.toggle( display )](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display)
- [.nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/), [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [.prevAll()](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/)

I used a class: active. This class is used to mark the current active element. Moreover, every time I need to move next or prev I move this class to the corresponding element. This class takes track of which img must be shown.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //
    // Toggle visibility
    //
    $('.slide:not(.active), .slide:not(.active) img').toggle(false);
    $('.slide.active, .slide.active img').toggle(true);

    //
    // closing preview....
    //
    $('.imgpreview .fa.fa-close').on('click', function(e) {
        $('.imgpreview, .slidepreview').css("display" , "none");
        //
        // ...remove active class and toggle visibility
        //
        $('.imgpreview, .slidepreview').find('.active, .active img').toggleClass(false).removeClass('active');
    });

    //
    // on prev....
    //
    $(".prev").on('click', function(e) {
        //
        // get the active element and so the previous one
        //
        var active = $(this).nextAll('.slide.active');
        var prev = active.prev('.slide');
        if (prev.length == 0) {
            //
            // if at the beginning take the last one
            //
            prev = $(this).nextAll('.slide').last();
        }
        //
        // move active class and toggle visibility
        //
        active.removeClass('active');
        prev.addClass('active').find('img').andSelf().toggle(true);
        $('.slide:not(.active), .slide:not(.active) img').toggle(false);
    });

    $(".next").on('click', function(e) {
        //
        // get the active element and so the next one
        //
        var active = $(this).prevAll('.slide.active');
        var next = active.next('.slide');
        if (next.length == 0) {
            //
            // if at the end take the first one
            //
            next = $(this).prevAll('.slide').last();
        }
        //
        // move active class and toggle visibility
        //
        active.removeClass('active');
        next.addClass('active').find('img').andSelf().toggle(true);
        $('.slide:not(.active), .slide:not(.active) img').toggle(false);
    });

    $(".slide img").on('click', function(e) {
        //
        // take the index of curr element in the parent element
        //
        var idx = $(this).closest('div.slide').index();
        var no = $(this).data('no');

        $('.imgpreview, .no_' + no).css('display' , 'flex');
        $('.no_' + no).children().eq(idx).addClass('active');
        $('.no_' + no).find('.slide:not(.active), .slide:not(.active) img').toggle(false);
        $('.no_' + no).find('.slide.active, .slide.active img').toggle(true);

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/css/font-awesome.css">


<div class="portfolio-slideshow">
    <a class="prev">❮</a>
    <div class="slide active"> <img src="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/img/dailyui/008.png" class="slideimg_0" data-no="0"></div>
    <div class="slide"> <img src="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/img/dailyui/007.jpg" class="slideimg_0" data-no="0"></div>
    <div class="slide"> <img src="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/img/dailyui/006.jpg" class="slideimg_0" data-no="0"></div>
    <div class="slide"> <img src="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/img/dailyui/003.jpg" class="slideimg_0" data-no="0"></div>
    <a class="next">❯</a>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-slideshow">
    <a class="prev">❮</a>
    <div class="slide active"> <img src="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/img/dailyui/008.png" class="slideimg_2" data-no="2"></div>
    <div class="slide"> <img src="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/img/dailyui/007.jpg" class="slideimg_2" data-no="2"></div>
    <div class="slide"> <img src="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/img/dailyui/006.jpg" class="slideimg_2" data-no="2"> </div>
    <div class="slide"> <img src="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/img/dailyui/003.jpg" class="slideimg_2" data-no="2"></div>
    <a class="next">❯</a>
</div>

<div class="imgpreview">
    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
    <div class="slidepreview no_0">
        <a class="prev" onclick="slide(1,-1)">❮</a>
        <div class="slide"> <img src="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/img/dailyui/008.png" class="slideimg_1"></div>
        <div class="slide"> <img src="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/img/dailyui/007.jpg" class="slideimg_1"></div>
        <div class="slide"> <img src="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/img/dailyui/006.jpg" class="slideimg_1"></div>
        <div class="slide"> <img src="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/img/dailyui/003.jpg" class="slideimg_1"></div>
        <a class="next">❯</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slidepreview no_2">
        <a class="prev">❮</a>
        <div class="slide"> <img src="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/img/dailyui/008.png" class="slideimg_3"></div>
        <div class="slide"> <img src="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/img/dailyui/007.jpg" class="slideimg_3"></div>
        <div class="slide"> <img src="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/img/dailyui/006.jpg" class="slideimg_3"></div>
        <div class="slide"> <img src="http://beta.eduardstefan.com/img/dailyui/003.jpg" class="slideimg_3"></div>
        <a class="next">❯</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the time used to tell me this.
I'll try to use what you said!

Comment: @EduardStefan Snippet updated: on closing preview....remove active and toggle visibility from preview itself. Thanks you so much and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

At least one problem is here:

```
var no = $(this).attr('data-no');
var no2 = no + 1;
```

`no` is a string so if `no` is "0", then `no + 1` is "01", so instead you can do this:

```
var no = $(this).attr('data-no');
var no2 = Number(no) + 1;
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmwdZb?editors=1111

Beyond that, why re-invent the wheel? There are plenty of good slideshow plugins available.

Comment: I did what you said but now it goes like this:
Let's say that I open the first slideshow with the first photo available, it is ok, but when i press next * doing slide(1,1) *, the slideIndex instead of becoming 0+1=1 it becomes 01 and all the other slideshows becomes unusable :(

Comment: About the why I not use a plugin, I haven't found one that will suit me